# jQuery-how to limit the event handler's scope

Tags: jquery, html

I have made a menu and it has several menu item. Clicking each menu item will trigger a drop down effect. The problem here is when I click first menu item, the second menu item will also has the drop down effect. So how should I modify the jQuery? Thanks in advance!
Here is the Html code.

```
            <nav>
                <ul class="category">
                    <li ><a href="" >News</a>
                        <div class="menu_container">
                            <ul class="menu">
                                <li>World News</li>
                                <li>Business News</li>
                                <li>Weather News</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="">Sports</a>
                        <div class="menu_container">
                            <ul class="menu">
                                <li>World News</li>
                                <li>Business News</li>
                                <li>Weather News</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                </ul>
         </nav>
```

Here is the jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var $menuHeight=$('.menu').height(),menuOpen=false;
$('.category li>a').click(function(event){

    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('triRotation');
    if(!menuOpen){
        $('.menu_container').height($menuHeight);

        menuOpen=true;
    }
    else{
        $('.menu_container').height(0);

        menuOpen=false;
    }
});});
```

Comment: Assign `id` to your menu and create a dropdown effect only for the clicked menu by using the `id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the div next to the clicked menu item with [.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) and instead of using a variable to know if the menu its visible i would use is("[:visible](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)")

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqWKbp)

```
$(function() {
  $('.category li>a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('triRotation');

    var $menuContainer = $(this).next("div");

    if ($menuContainer.is(":visible")) {
      $menuContainer.hide();
    } else {
      $menuContainer.show();
    }
  });
});
```